# How are interface types handled between functions?

Tags: go

I have some questions about interfaces, especially when these interfaces are passed between functions.

I understand that interfaces are satisfied implicitly, meaning the following code is valid:

```
type itemX struct {}
func (x *itemX) Do() string {
    return "itemX"
}

type Itf interface {
    Do() string
}

func test(i Itf) string {
    return i.Do()
}

func main() {
    x := new(itemX)
    str := test(x)  // valid, since x implicitly satisfies Itf
}
```

However, it is not so clear what happens or what the **type contract** is like when I start passing *interfaces between functions*. An example:

```
// itemX, Itf, and test have the same declaration as the above snippet

func returnsItf(i Itf) Itf {
    return i
}

func returnsTypeAssertedX(i Itf) Itf {
    return i.(*itemX)
}

func takeItf(i Itf) {}

func takeX(x *itemX) {}

func main() {
    x := new(itemX)
    var i Itf = x

    a := returnsItf(i)   // returns type Itf
    _ = takeItf(a)       // no error

    b := returnsTypeAssertedX(i)
    _ = takeItf(b) // no error, since *itemX implements Itf
    _ = takeX(b)   // error, cannot use b (type Itf as *itemX)
}
```

There seems to be some hidden behavior when an interface is passed out as a function return. If the return is `*itemX` and type is `Itf`, the return is transformed into `Itf` before the function frame is terminated.

So, this implicit check (concrete -> interface if type is interface) is done *twice* per function call:

- at the start of each function call,
- and at the end.

Is my understanding of this implicit transformation correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An interface is a data type that has two members: The type of the underlying object, and a pointer to that object. So, wen you use a non-interface type in a context that needs an interface, the compiler constructs an interface type from that value, and uses that.

```
func returnsTypeAssertedX(i Itf) Itf {
    return i.(*itemX)
}
```

In the above function, it first type-asserts that the passed in argument is of the required type, and then converts the underlying value of the argument back to an interface.

```
b := returnsTypeAssertedX(i)
_ = takeX(b)
```

The above will not work, because `b` is an `interface{}`, and `takeX` requires an `*itemX`. However, this would work:

```
takeX(b.(*itemX))
```